# What are differences/advantages of Invite vs. Referral modules?

Tags: 7

Are there any distinct advantages for choosing either the Invite or Referral modules for the purpose of allowing existing site users to get their friends to check out the site and create an account?

I'm trying to determine which module will be the best solution for us, but they seem like they essentially do the same thing. Am I wrong?

We'll want to be able to award points for successful sign ups, and maybe some other type or rules integration to reward those who get more people to sign up.

- http://drupal.org/project/invite
- http://drupal.org/project/referral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Invite](http://drupal.org/project/invite) module is [more popular](http://drupal.org/project/usage/invite) and is a more active project. The last commit was 4 weeks ago, while [User Referral](http://drupal.org/project/referral) git repository has been inactive for more than 1 year. Considering that the last version of User Referral is still in beta, I would check Invite first.

Back in 2007, there was an idea of [merging the two into Invite](http://drupal.org/node/126653), but apparently did not happen.

You can see some differences between them discussed in the previous link. Some of them are:

- Invite sends a coded registration link by e-mail whereas User Referral displays it.
- Referral's tracking uses a session variable to store referral information. Invite's tracking code is lost if the user moves away from the registration page.
- Invite codes are always unique and can be used only once.
- Invite codes have an expiry date.
- User Referral display a referral link (such as referral/123) in the user's page.

They also seem to provide integrations with different modules.